# Interactive program ignores keystrokes on a CygWin OpenSSH Server

Tags: ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin, openssh

I am running Windows 7 SP1.

I have installed CygWin with OpenSSH, so now I have a running SSH Daemon that seems to be working OK, except for a problem with an interactive command-line program that requires keystrokes to be managed.

This is the program ([OCLHashCat](http://hashcat.net), a GPU number cruncher):

```
D:\Temporal\>d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat\oclhashcat64.exe Test.hccap -m 2500 -a 3 ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d   | tee Resultado.txt

oclHashcat v1.31 starting...

WARN: ADL_Overdrive6_FanSpeed_Get(): -5

Device #1: Bonaire, 1024MB, 1050Mhz, 12MCU
Device #2: Tahiti, 3072MB, 900Mhz, 28MCU

Hashes: 1 hashes; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 8 bits, 256 entries, 0x000000ff mask, 1024 bytes
Applicable Optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
Watchdog: Temperature abort trigger set to 90c
Watchdog: Temperature retain trigger set to 80c
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259320 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92404 bytes)
Device #1: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Bonaire_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30496 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/m02500.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (259428 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/markov_le_v1.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (92388 bytes)
Device #2: Kernel d:\Programas\HashCat\OCLHashCat/kernels/4098/bzero.Tahiti_1573.4_1573.4 (VM).kernel (30492 bytes)

[s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [b]ypass [q]uit => s
q
qStopped

Luis-@Windu /cygdrive/d/Temporal/
$
```

As you can see, I tried by pressing <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>q</kbd> , but the interactive program did not respond to keystrokes until I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Furthermore, the process `oclhashcat64.exe` remained in memory, and I had to kill it manually.

I have checked with these SSH clients; I think all of them are in their latest version:

- Putty.
- GNU SSH command line tool (included in modern Ubuntu, for example).
- Bitvise SSH Client.

I have installed (on another TCP port) the [Bitvise SSH server](http://www.bitvise.com) too, and I don’t have this keystrokes problem using it, so it could be some sort of OpenSSH matter.

The issue is I need access to CygWin’s commands, so I need to connect via the OpenSSH version installed within CygWin. The Bitvise is one only gives me access to CMD Shell or PowerShell.
I can not try this OCLHashCat program in another computer or operating system, due to it requires GPU high-end devices, perfect drivers configuration, etc…

How could I solve the keystroke issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that, as for now (November 2014), the issue is a limitation on the original program. [Here](https://hashcat.net/trac/ticket/535) is the error reporting ticket.